# why doesn't my ajax work

Tags: ajax

It's supposed to display 172-ajax-include.php when the user clicks the submit button. But it doesn't work. I think I did it right. Can't figure out what I did wrong.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function load()
    { /* start function load */
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
        { /* 1 if start */

       xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

        } /* 1 if end */
        else
        {  /* 1 else start */  
         xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');   
        } /* 1 else end */

        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200 /* the 200  makes sure that it's not empty*/)
        { /* 2 if start */
            document.getElementById('adiv'),innerHTML =  xmlhttp.responseText;
        } /* 2 if end */

        xmlhttp.open('GET', '172-ajax-include.php', true);
        xmlhttp.send();
        }



    } /* end function load */
    </script>

</head>
<body>

    <input type="submit" onclick="load();">
    <div id="adiv"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

open() and send() must be placed outside the onreadystatechange handler.

```
 xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() 
    {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)
        { /* 2 if start */
            document.getElementById('adiv'),innerHTML =  xmlhttp.responseText;
        } /* 2 if end */
     };
   xmlhttp.open('GET', '172-ajax-include.php', true);
   xmlhttp.send();
```

EDIT:

Change html button

```
<input type"button" onclick="load()" value="Show"/>
```

Comment: Thanks AVD, but it's still not working after I tried that. Any ideas?

Comment: Change button type. <input type="button" />

Comment: Thanks dude. I also messed up on the last if statement. I put a comma instead of a period. YES! Got it to work.